# How to combine two or more arrays in ci active record?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Below is piece of code in my ci model

```
    $project_type_ids = $this->input->post('project_type_ids');
    $project_status_ids = $this->input->post('project_status_ids');

    $this->db->select('project_title, lat, lang, type');
    $this->db->from('projects');
    $this->db->join('project_type', 'project_type.id = projects.project_type_id');
    $this->db->join('project_status', 'project_status.id = projects.project_status_id');
    $this->db->where_in("project_type_id",$project_type_ids);
    $this->db->where($this->db->where_in("project_status_id",$project_status_ids));
    $result = $this->db->get();
```

1. is there something like $this->db->and_where_in() in ci?
   I could not find such active record syntax in ci user guide.
   Note that $project_type_ids and $project_status_ids are both arrays passed to model through ajax from front end.
2. using `$this->db->last_query();` i get the query and its query result returned from database but there is also a warning as below:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:  Illegal offset type
>
> Filename:
>   database/DB_active_rec.php
>
> Line Number: 402

---

```
SELECT `project_title`, `lat`, `lang`, `type`
  FROM (`projects`)
  JOIN `project_type` ON `project_type`.`id` = `projects`.`project_type_id`
JOIN `project_status` ON `project_status`.`id` = `projects`.`project_status_id`
WHERE `project_type_id` IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') 
AND `project_status_id` IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

Comment: In your provided code what you are trying to achieve with second last line ?

Comment: I want to have something like "and project_status_id in(my_array);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$this->db->where($this->db->where_in("project_status_id",$project_status_ids));
```

to

```
$this->db->where_in("project_status_id",$project_status_ids);
```